# Can we format as to how the Model Form displays in Django on template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

So I am using the django user model (from django.contrib.auth.models import User) and created a Model Form by using the ModelForm (from django.forms import ModelForm). When i display it on the template it shows up on the select boxes as usernames. i want to display it is first_name and last_name.

Thisis the code I am using for form in HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ title }}</legend>

        {% for field in form %} {% if field.errors %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="controls col-sm-10">
                {{ field }}
                <p class="formError">
                    {% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="controls col-sm-10">
                {{ field }} {% if field.help_text %}
                <p class="help-inline"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-actions" style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 30px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and override `label_from_instance` to display the first and last name.

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class UserChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

Then use the choice field in your model form.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = UserChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can this be done if User is a foregin_key to another model? like the model form is for another model but user is one of the fields in the model.

Comment: The above form `MyModelForm` is for a model `MyModel` which has a foreign key to `User`. The custom choice field means that the users will be displayed as `<first_name> <last_name>` instead of `<username>`. Isn't that what you want? If not, please update your answer with some code, to help explain.

Comment: yes that is what I want. I have a model named PermissionAssignment

Comment: class PermissionAssignment(models.Model):
    permissionAssignmentID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    projectID_fk = models.ForeignKey(Project, default=None, null=True)
    userID_fk = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)

This is the model I have for which I am creating the form

Comment: The `UserChoiceField` above should work if you add `userID_fk = UserChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())` to your model form.

Comment: gives 'name 'UserChoiceField' is not defined' error.

Comment: You need to add the `UserChoiceField` above to your code.

Comment: `class UserChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)

class permissionsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PermissionAssignment
        UserChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
        fields=[ 'userID_fk', 'userLevel', 'dataAccess' ]` this is what I did

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, it's impossible to read. Update your original question, and include the full traceback.

Comment: I am sorry. I updated the question with what i tried.

Comment: It should be `userID_fk = UserChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())`, and that code should be in `permissionsForm`, not in the `Meta` class.